# Is it possible to fetch a VM by IP address,without knowing resource group, in Node.js Runtime on Azure Function?

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-functions

I am running Node.js in Azure Function and I am trying to retrieve the resource group  and name of a VM while only knowing the IP that was sent. Is it possible to retrieve all Public IP addresses associated with a subscription using Node.js SDK in Azure?

In powershell I can write  `az network public-ip list` which will provide a JSON which contains information like:

```
"id": "/subscriptions/444444-4444-43444d8-44444c/resourceGroups/testserver/providers/Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses/publicip",
"idleTimeoutInMinutes": 4,
"ipAddress": "55.55.55.55",
```

However in Node when calling a similar function `networkClient.PublicIPAddresses.listAll()` I receive a list of id's but not an  IP address. ie:

```
[1/25/2019 7:19:47 PM]     publicIPAddressVersion: 'IPv4',
[1/25/2019 7:19:47 PM]     ipConfiguration:
[1/25/2019 7:19:47 PM]      { id:
[1/25/2019 7:19:47 PM]         '/subscriptions/444444-4444-43444d8-44444/resourceGroups/TEST/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/test-vm1968/ipConfigurations/ipconfig1' },
```

Is it possible in Node to fetch all public IP's and use that to determine the Resource group and associated VM?

Thank you.

Comment: i didnt work with nodejs sdk, but my guess is: you need to iterate over resource ids and get each individual resource until you find the one with the matching ip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible in Node. On Azure, all SDKs are built by wrapping the REST APIs. So if you can find out the REST API of the feature you want, you also can use the related SDK API for your used language.

There is a REST API [`PublicIPAddress(Preview) - List All`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/virtualnetwork/publicipaddress(preview)/listall) which response is same with the result of the command `az network public-ip list`. We must note the value of the required parameter `api-version` is `2018-11-01`, and it's a newest version of an ARM API.

Considering for different `api-version` values used in the different SDK versions, first of all to upgrade the `azure-arm-network` package version to newest via `npm update azure-arm-network --save`, then to run the code like below which refer to the sample code [`vm-sample.js`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-node/blob/master/examples/ARM/compute/vm-sample.js) ` in GitHub.

```
var util = require('util');
var path = require('path');
var msRestAzure = require('ms-rest-azure');
var NetworkManagementClient = require('azure-arm-network');

var FileTokenCache = require('../../lib/util/fileTokenCache');
var tokenCache = new FileTokenCache(path.resolve(path.join(__dirname, '../../test/tmp/tokenstore.json')));

//Environment Setup
_validateEnvironmentVariables();
var clientId = process.env['CLIENT_ID'];
var domain = process.env['DOMAIN'];
var secret = process.env['APPLICATION_SECRET'];
var subscriptionId = process.env['AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID'];
var credentials = new msRestAzure.ApplicationTokenCredentials(clientId, domain, secret, { 'tokenCache': tokenCache });
var networkClient = new NetworkManagementClient(credentials, subscriptionId);

function listAllPublicIP(options, callback) {
    return networkClient.publicIPAddresses.listAll(options, callback);
}
```

You can check the API calling above whether correctly calls the correct REST API with the query paramater `api-version=2018-11-01` via `Fiddler`.

Also, you can directly call the REST API with the `Authorization` header which value get from the `credentials` variable of the code above.

Comment: Thanks Peter, This was very helpful!